# Data encapsulation for db access: Do I always have to write public + private methods?

Tags: java, database, encapsulation

A colleague of my says that this is data encapsulation and it has to be done when using database access:

```
public String foo(final int x) {
  return fooHidden(x);
}

private String fooHidden(final int x) {
  return db.lookFor(x);
}
```

I simplified the code to be more readable, but it's still the same structure.
So in my opinion this is not data encapsulation, it doesn't hide anything, because the return value and the transfer parameter are equal. So for me, it would make no difference to write:

```
public String fooHidden(final int x) {
  return db.lookFor(x);
}
```

The upper solution would make sense for me if we overlay the method or have other parameters for the private method which use class internal attributes, but this is not the case.

Can you tell me who is right? How would you accomplish real data encapsulation for this case?

Comment: I assume that both methods are in the same class - in this concrete example it does not make much sense to do that.
What makes sense is to hide database (which is actually an implementation detail) behind some interface (e.g.: interface SomeDataRepository { ... }) so you will not be calling database directly.

Comment: That's right, they are both in the same class. To be more specific: This class use the DSLContext and access the database like this: "dslContext.select(..).from(..).fetch(..)". I guess it would be the better, like you said, to write an interface for this database queries.

Comment: It might be _better still_ to consider looking at already-available tools like Querydsl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two methods implementations are quite the same, i.e. in your case it makes no difference, but semantically speaking, it would make more sense to have:

```
public String foo(final int x) {
  return db.lookFor(x);
}
```

Note the name `foo` and not `fooHidden` to make reference to publicly provided method (*hidden* would otherwise imply you are exposing a *supposed-to-be-private* method).

Meanwhile, both implementation still hide the `db` field, which should be **hidden from class callers and `private` to the wrapping class**, hence ***encapsulated***.
*So encapsulation is about the field state and not the method implementations*.

This implies that the class structure should be as follows in a whole:

```
public class MyClass {

  private db; // must be private, otherwise you'll be violating the encapsulation rule

  public String foo(final int x) {
    return db.lookFor(x);
  }

}
```

Going back to the OP question:

> Do I always have to write public **methods** + private methods?

The question should instead be: *Do I always have to write **public** + private **fields**?*

And I would state that in major cases, **you should do it yes**.
Meanwhile, there may be design requirements that need to have the rule broken.

Encapsulation, in *Java*, is about *Access Modifiers*; meaning what *fields / methods* you make public thus accessible for the outside world.

Here is what [what Martin Fowler states about Access Modifiers](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/AccessModifier.html):

> Object-oriented languages divide a program into modules called classes. Each class contains features, which consist of data (fields) and methods. (Not all languages use these terms, but they'll do for this.) Languages have various rules about what other classes can access the features of a class, these are often based on access modifiers that apply to a class.

Comment: Just to be sure: You say that data encapsulation has nothing to do with methods? Just based on the visibility of attributes?

Comment: Exactly, what is commonly referred to as *Access Modifiers*. I've updated the answer to detail that.